# Prove that $\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil}{2}\right\rfloor+\cdots=n-1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions, trees, binary

> Prove that, for $n\in \Bbb{Z}^+$,
> $$\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil}{2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{\left\lceil\frac{\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil}{2}\right\rceil}{2}\right\rfloor+\cdots = n - 1\,,$$
> where there are $\lceil{\log_2n}\rceil$ addends on the left-hand side.

I don't know how I could prove this. Any ideas? There is an intimate relationship here with a binary tree where each addend is the number of nodes on that layer, and $n$ is the number of leaves.

Comment: Write $$f(n):=\left\lceil\dfrac{n}{2}\right\rceil$$ for each positive integer $n$.  Let $f_k$ be the $k$-time iteration of $f$ for $k=0,1,2,\ldots$ (i.e., $f_0$ is the identity function, and $f_k:=f_{k-1}\circ f$ for all $k=1,2,\ldots$), and define $$g_k(n):=\left\lfloor\dfrac{f_{k-1}(n)}{2}\right\rfloor$$ for all $k=1,2,3,\ldots$.  Prove that $g_k(n)$ is the number of all integers $m$ such that $2\leq m\leq n$ and $$m\equiv 2^{k-1}+1\pmod{2^k}\,.\tag{*}$$  Show also that, for every integer $m$ such that $2\leq m\leq n$, there exists a unique positive integer $k$ such that (*) is true

Comment: Coincidence that $\frac{\displaystyle\int_{0}^{n}\lfloor x\rfloor\, dx}{\displaystyle\int_{0}^{n} \{x\}\, dx}=n-1$ ?

Answer (score 5):

One may use $n=\lfloor n/2\rfloor+\lceil n/2\rceil$ recursively. So (compare to the comment by @Batominovski), if $f(n)=\lceil n/2\rceil$ and $g(n)=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$, then $n=g(n)+f(n)=g(n)+g(f(n))+f(f(n))=\ldots$, i.e. $$n=f_m(n)+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}g(f_k(n))\qquad \big[f_0(n)=n,\quad f_{k+1}(n)=f(f_k(n))\big]$$ (induction on $m$). Now put $m=\lceil\log_2 n\rceil$ and notice (well, prove) that $f_m(n)=1$.

> The latter is accomplished by noting that we also have $$f_{k+1}(n)=f_k(f(n))=f_k(\lceil n/2\rceil),$$ so that $2^{k-1}<n\leqslant 2^k\implies f_k(n)=1$ holds by induction on $k$.

Answer (score 2):

Any positive integer $n$ satisfies the following equation:

$$
n=\sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor\log_{2}{n}\right\rfloor}{\left(a_{i}2^{i}\right)}
$$

Substitute it to your equation to obtain:

$$
\begin{aligned}
<your\ equation>&=\sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor\log_{2}{n}\right\rfloor}{\left(a_{i}\left(2^{0}+\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}{2^{j}}\right)\right)}-a_{0}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor\log_{2}{n}\right\rfloor}{\left(a_{i}2^{i}\right)}-a_{0}\\
&=n-1
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: what is $a_i$??

Comment: $a_{i}$ is either $0$ or $1$. Basically $i$-th digit of $n$ in base $2$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \forall (x,n) \in \mathbb{R}×\mathbb{N}, \: \left \lfloor \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{n} \right \rfloor = \left \lfloor \frac{x}{n} \right \rfloor$$

$$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, \: n=\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor + \left \lceil \frac{n}{2} \right \rceil$$

Applying Hermite's identity, we have
\begin{equation} n= \left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \right \rfloor \end{equation}

Therefore $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \; \left \lceil \frac{n}{2} \right \rceil = \left \lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \right \rfloor$$

Define a function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ \begin{align*} f(n) &= \left \lceil \frac{n}{2} \right \rceil = \left \lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \right \rfloor \\ f^{[2]}(n)&=f(f(n)); \; \; f^{[k]}(n)=f(f^{[k-1]}(n)) \end{align*}

Then
\begin{align*} f(f(n)) &= \left \lfloor \frac{\left \lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \right \rfloor + 1}{2} \right \rfloor = \left \lfloor \frac{\left \lfloor \frac{n+1+2}{2} \right \rfloor}{2} \right \rfloor \\ &= \left \lfloor \frac{n+2^0+2^1}{2^2} \right \rfloor \end{align*}

it is not difficult to show by induction that:

\begin{align*} f^{[k]}(n) &= \left \lfloor \frac{n+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} 2^j}{2^k} \right \rfloor = \left \lfloor \frac{n+2^k-1}{2^k} \right \rfloor \\ &=\left \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2^k} \right \rfloor +1 \end{align*}

We see that the above sum is equivalent to
\begin{align*} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left \lfloor \frac{f^{[k]}(n)}{2} \right \rfloor 
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left \lfloor \frac{f^{[k]}(n)-1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \right \rfloor \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left \lfloor f^{[k]}(n)-1 \right \rfloor - \left \lfloor \frac{f^{[k]}(n)-1}{2} \right \rfloor \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2^k} \right \rfloor - \left \lfloor \frac{\left \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2^k} \right \rfloor}{2} \right \rfloor \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2^k} \right \rfloor - \left \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2^{k+1}} \right \rfloor \\ &= \left \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2^0} \right \rfloor = n-1 \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to the prior post, only the following lemmas to be considered (also the ones i'd mentioned in the previous post):
$$\forall (x,n)\in \mathbb{R}×\mathbb{N}, \; \left \lceil \frac{\lceil x \rceil}{n} \right \rceil = \left \lceil \frac{x}{n} \right \rceil$$
or equivalently,
$$\forall (m,n,x)\in \mathbb{Z}×\mathbb{N}×\mathbb{R}, \: \left\lceil \frac{\lceil x \rceil + m}{n} \right\rceil = \left\lceil \frac{x+m}{n} \right\rceil$$
$$\forall (a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}×\mathbb{N}, \; \left\lceil \frac{a}{b} \right\rceil = \left\lfloor \frac{a-1}{b} \right \rfloor +1 \iff \left\lfloor \frac{a}{b} \right \rfloor = \left\lceil \frac{a+1}{b} \right\rceil - 1$$
Last, but not least
$$\forall (x,n)\in \mathbb{R}×\mathbb{N}, \; \lceil nx \rceil = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left\lceil x-\frac{k}{n} \right\rceil$$
or in other words, 
Hermite's Ceiling Function Identity (which can easily be obtained by substituting $x\to -x$ into the Hermite's Floor Function Identity)

The validity of all of these shall be left as exercises to the readers

Substituting for n=2 and $x\to x/2$ on the last lemma,
\begin{align} \lceil x \rceil = \left\lceil \frac{x-1}{2}\right\rceil + \left\lceil \frac{x}{2} \right\rceil \end{align}

Let $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that   $$f(n) = \left \lceil \frac{n}{2} \right \rceil$$

\begin{align*} f_k(n) &= \underbrace{f(f(...(f(n))...))}_{\text{k times}} \\ \\ &= \left \lceil \frac{\left \lceil \frac{...\left \lceil \tfrac{n}{2} \right \rceil ...}{2} \right \rceil}{2} \right \rceil = \left \lceil \frac{n}{2^k} \right \rceil \end{align*}

The above sum is then equivalent to
\begin{align*} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left \lfloor \frac{f_k(n)}{2} \right \rfloor &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( \left \lceil \frac{f_k(n)+1}{2} \right \rceil-1 \right) \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left\lceil \frac{\left\lceil \frac{n}{2^k} \right\rceil -1}{2} \right\rceil = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left\lceil \frac{\frac{n}{2^k}-1}{2} \right\rceil \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left\lceil \frac{n}{2^{k+1}} - \frac{1}{2} \right\rceil \\ &= \lim_{m\to\infty} \, \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \left\lceil \frac{n}{2^k} \right\rceil - \left\lceil \frac{n}{2^{k+1}} \right \rceil \\ &= \lim_{m\to\infty} n-\left\lceil \frac{n}{2^m} \right \rceil \end{align*}
Set $M=\left\lceil \log_2(n+1) \right\rceil \iff 0<2^{M-1}\leq n < 2^M  $ 
Thus
$$ \forall m\in [M,\infty) \cap \mathbb{N} ,\; \; 0<\frac{n}{2^m}<1 \implies \left\lceil \frac{n}{2^m} \right\rceil = 1 $$
Therefore, as $m\to \infty, m\in \mathbb{N}$, one obtains
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{f_k(n)}{2} \right\rfloor= \lim_{m\to \infty} n - \left\lceil \frac{n}{2^m} \right \rceil = n-1$$

as was to be demonstrated.

∎